# Symbolizing changes in housing condition over time using ArcMap?

Tags: arcmap

I have two polygon layers, one from 2015 and the other from 2018. Each layer has an attribute field with a number from 1-14 which describes the physical conditions of houses. There are 15,000+ houses in each layer.

What I'd like to do using ArcMap is to create a map that answers the following question:

*Are the housing conditions in 2018 better, the same, or worse than 2015?*

Image below: YEAR 2015

[image]

Image below: YEAR 2018

[image]

Comment: What exactly are you trying to ask? Are the housing conditions better for particular residents? For sections of the area? Or on average for the area as a whole? It's not very clear what you're trying to achieve from your question.

Comment: If you also want to ask how to do this in QGIS, please do that in a separate question.

Comment: Assuming the polygons represent parcels, is there a parcelID that you can use to join the two different parcel tables?

Answer (score 1):

[Spatial Join](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/tools/analysis-toolbox/spatial-join.htm) the data from 2015 to 2018 using match option HAVE_THEIR_CENTER_IN. This will join the attributes from 2015 to the attribute table of the 2018 feature class.

Then add a field and calculate using [Field Calculator with some if/else statements](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/manage-data/tables/calculate-field-examples.htm#ESRI_SECTION1_11EAB368A53B4D1C9618A58A1B09F9D0) to check for each house if the condition is better or worse. This field can be used to symbolize better/worse like in your screenshots.

If you also want to check if overall condition has improved, use [Summary Statistics](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/tools/analysis-toolbox/summary-statistics.htm) to Count number of better or worse.

Another way would be: [Enabling time on your data](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/map/time/enabling-time-on-your-data.htm). But probably not worth the effort when you only have two "times", 2015 and 2018.